# for loop of shell in makefile

Tags: makefile

I wrote a makefile and hope it could generate files in sequence like this

```
1.out
2.out
3.out
```

makefile

```sh
TOUCH := $(shell for n in 'seq 1 3'; do echo $$n ;done)
.PHONY: test
test:
    @$(TOUCH)
```

[OK] make result:

```
1
2
3
```

However, when I replaced **echo** with **touch**,

```
TOUCH := $(shell for n in 'seq 1 3'; do touch $$n.out ;done)
```

[Wrong] make result:

```
1
seq
3.out
```

Comment: If you want to use `make` like this, why not just write a shell script instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be mixing two completely separate constructs here.

```
VARIABLE := value
```

will assign `value` to variable.

```
VARIABLE := $(shell echo value)
```

will use the shell to produce a string, then assign that string to `VARIABLE`.  This happens when the `Makefile` is being parsed, i.e. before Make tries to actually execute any recipes.

I would imagine you are looking for this instead:

```
TOUCH := for n in $$(seq 1 3); do touch $$n.out; done
.PHONY: test
test:
        @$(TOUCH)
```

which of course might as well be inlined;

```
.PHONY: test
test:
        @for n in $$(seq 1 3); do touch $$n.out; done
```

A better design is to put Make in charge, though:

```
.PHONY: test
test: 1.out 2.out 3.out
%.out:
        @touch $@
```

(Personally, I would leave out the `@` prefix everywhere so you can see what's happening.  Run with `make -s` once you have stuff debugged if the output bothers you.)

Comment: VARIABLE := $(shell bla bla bla) will use the shell to produce a string. Thanks. It's clearer now. But the **touch** version is just changing command from **echo** and plus a **.out** as postfix. Why is the result totally different ?

Comment: I don't think you have transcribed the quotes correctly.  The first command would also not work if it had single quotes.  I'm guessing you had proper backquotes originally, then erroneously changed them to regular straight apostrophes even without noticing.  I believe you could verify this by copy+pasting what you wrote here and trying again.

Comment: I tried again **echo** case. The single or double quote doesn't matter but when I echo $$n.out, it showed "seq: invalid floating point argument: 3.out", which mean $$n could accept only number format in this case.

Comment: That is not a correct analysis at all.  The error message means you ended up with something like `$(seq 1 3.out)` instead of `$(seq 1 3)`.

Comment: It is not a matter of single versus double quotes, it is a matter of `\` ` versus `'`.

Comment: Got it now. And your answer is workable. Really thanks for your help !

Comment: Why not combine the  two: `INTS := $(shell seq 1 3)`  / `OUTS := $(INTS:=.out)` / `test: $(OUTS)`

Comment: We could improve further, by using the dependency `test: $(addsuffix .out,1 2 3)`

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues at play here.

You are using single quotes instead of backticks in your shell code. Single quotes create strings. Backticks execute commands.

So when you write `for n in 'seq 1 3'; do echo $$n; done` what the shell is doing is looping over the list of the single string "seq 1 3" not over the numbers 1, 2, and 3.

That results in a value for `TOUCH` of "seq 1 3".

When you then expand `TOUCH` on the rule `@$(TOUCH)` line that line becomes `@seq 1 3` which the shell then executes for you and outputs

```
1
2
3
```

but not for the reason you thought. (Drop the leading `@` and you'll see it.)

Given that information if we look at the non-working example

```
TOUCH := $(shell for n in 'seq 1 3'; do touch $$n.out ;done)
```

and take the loop body `touch $$n.out` and replace `$$n` with the string "seq 1 3" to get `touch seq 1 3.out`.

Which gets us a `$(shell)` call which runs `touch seq 1 3.out` and creates the files you list in your post and an empty `TOUCH` variable. Which explains why (though you didn't ask) you get `make: Nothing to be done for \`test'`as output from running`make`.

I should also point out, explicitly, that your `echo`/`touch` running is being done during the `$(shell)` call and **not** during the `test` rule execution. That's likely not what you want. Either don't use a simply expanded `:=` variable or put the command to run in the variable and don't use `$(shell)`.

Comment: Plus one for a good analysis, but worth more — and screw SO's new rule that you can't write +1 at the start of a comment.  Sorry, but that is a silly edict, and therefore will be ignored and abused whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But actually "for n in 'seq 1 3'; do echo $$n; done" will echo 1 2 3 in sequence. Why is that ?

Comment: It doesn't, not with those quotes.  With proper backquotes, the command `for n in \`seq 1 3\`; do ...` (which can also, more clearly and portably, be written `for f in $(seq 1 3); do ...`) performs roughly the same as you would expect `for n in $(shell seq 1 3)` if we switch back to GNU Make syntax.